# Why this ArrayList code gets an error?

Tags: java, arraylist

I was expected `1 c 3 o` for the result. But only got `1 c 3 o 5 c`.
What's wrong with the code?

```
ArrayList<String> A_array= new ArrayList<>();

A_array.add(0,"c");   B_array.add(0,1);
A_array.add(1,"c");   B_array.add(1,2);
A_array.add(2,"o");   B_array.add(2,3);
A_array.add(3,"c");   B_array.add(3,4);
A_array.add(4,"c");   B_array.add(4,5);
A_array.add(5,"c");   B_array.add(5,6);    

for(int i=0;i<B_array.size()-1;i++)
{
   for(int j=i+1;j<B_array.size();j++)
   {
      if(A_array.get(i)==A_array.get(j))
      {
         B_array.remove(j);A_array.remove(j);
      }
   }
}
for(int i=0;i<B_array.size();i++)
{
   System.out.println(B_array.get(i)+" "+A_array.get(i));
}
```

Comment: don't use `==` to compare Strings, use `.equals()`

Comment: If you're going to modify lists while iterating through them, you should go through their contents backwards.

Comment: Whats the logic behind the expected result?

Comment: What is this code even supposed to do, and what attempts have you made to debug it? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [how to write the perfect question](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for more information.

Comment: What's the error? And what's `B_array`?

Comment: I wrote an [in-depth example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21647125/2071828) of what happens when you remove from a `List` when looping by index. I would recommended that you read it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're modifying the array and remove element, then you should update the index, here i would suggest to use iterator, and use `iterator.remove`.

```
for (Iterator<String> iterator = B_array.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String value = iterator.next();
    if(equals) {
        iterator.remove();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To safely remove objects from an `Iterable` such as a `List` while going through it, use [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

```
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String s = iterator.next();
    if(some comdition on s) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```